# Subset hyphenated JSON element in Polymer data binding

Tags: html, polymer

Consider the following JSON:

```
{"EMD-4091":["EMD-4084","EMD-4090"]}
```

which is the result of a fictitious `iron-ajax` call as follows:

```
<iron-ajax
  auto
  url="http://me.com/get/EMD-4091"
  handle-as="json"
  last-response="{{my_data}}">
</iron-ajax>
```

Suppose I need to refer to the inner array, say, in a `dom-repeat`: how would I refer to 'EMD-4091' in a data binding? e.g.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{my_data????}}> <!-- what should this be?-->
  <p>{{item}}</p>
</template>
```

If the data wasn't hyphenated this is a trivial task. The hyphen is the challenge I'm facing.

P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data binding can still parse the hyphenated key without a problem, so your binding would be:

```
items="{{my_data.EMD-4091}}"
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  "use strict";

  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties : {
      my_data: {
        type: Array,
        value: () => ({"EMD-4091":["EMD-4084","EMD-4090"]})
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[my_data.EMD-4091]]">
        <div>[[item]]</div>
      </template>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/JRVyvz?editors=1010)

Comment: I could swear I tried that to no avail. I'll give it a shot tomorrow and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: It worked. Another issue blocked me from seeing that it had worked earlier. One point for you, though ;-)